# Prove dual space Y* is subspace of X* if X is subspace of Y

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

We have ***V*** - vector space and ***U***, ***W*** ⊆ ***V*** (subspaces). ***U**** and ***W**** are the dual spaces accordingly. I have to prove that if ***U*** is subspace of ***W***, then ***W**** is subspace of ***U****. I am honestly baffled because the concept of duality is still fresh in my mind. What I tried is proving that ***W**** is closed around scalar multiplication and addition, but because it's a space consisting of functionals I don't know how to proceed. Any hints would be welcome.

Comment: Strange result... even in finite dimension it's not true...

Comment: If $X$ is a vector space, I will assume that $X^*$ denotes the vector space of all linear maps from $X$ to the scalar field. Thus, an element of $W^*$ is a function with domain $W$, so it cannot be an element of $U^*$ unless $U=W$ (in which case $U^*=W^*$ is trivially true). Thus, this result is false if $U \neq W$.

Comment: @azif00 thanks for the explanation. thats weird we had this on an exam. maybe i wrote it incorrectly...

Answer (score 2):

Let $U\subset W$, and $f \in W^*$. So
$$\forall w \in W, f(w) \in \mathbb{F}.$$
($\mathbb{F}$ is the scalar field). As $U \subset W$, then $\forall u \in U$, $u \in W$. Then, $f(u) \in \mathbb{F}, \forall u \in U$. So, as $f$ is linear in $W$, then $f$ is linear in $U$. Therefore, $f \in U^*$.